# What is the difference between flow and cannabis induced high?

Tags: emotion, psychopharmacology

I am doing research on flow. So far I [found out](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/17497/what-is-the-difference-between-work-engagement-and-flow) that flow is a short-term positive peak experience, but not a persistent state of mind. I wonder, what is the difference between flow and cannabis induced high? (The ICD-10 code is F12.0 [cannabinoid intoxication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substance_intoxication).)

Comment: How did you come to compare flow and cannabis use? Do you think cannabis usage is also associated with a "short-term positive peak experience"?

Comment: This question may need to be asked more precisely, since as stated below, flow is linked to activity while cannabis induced high is linked to the effect of a substance. In my eyes it would be interesting to know, whether experiencing flow is different with or without cannabis induced high. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Following your links I understand you are relating to:

> **[Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology))**: also known as the zone, is the mental state of operation in which a person performing an activity is fully immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity. In essence, flow is characterized by complete absorption in what one does and loses sense of space and time.

While the **[effects of cannabis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_cannabis#Short-term_effects)** intoxication include, but are not limited to:

- general alteration of conscious perception;
- euphoria;
- feelings of well-being;
- relaxation or stress reduction;
- increased appreciation of the arts, including humor and music;
- joviality;
- metacognition and introspection;
- enhanced recollection (episodic memory);
- increased sensuality;
- increased awareness of sensatio;
- increased libido and creativity;
- abstract or philosophical thinking;
- disruption of linear memory;
- paranoia or anxiety;
- greater enjoyment of food taste and aroma;
- enhanced enjoyment of music and comedy;
- marked distortions in the perception of time and space (where experiencing a "rush" of ideas from the bank of long-term memory can create the subjective impression of long elapsed time, while in reality only a short time has passed).

At higher doses:

- altered body image;
- auditory and/or visual illusions;
- pseudohallucinations;
- ataxia;
- rarely dissociative state (depersonalization and derealization);
- acute psychosis;

So in all, based on a cursory wikipedia search, I would say there are more differences than similarities between the two states of mind.